# Words under sum that's in a denominator

Tags: math-mode, math-operators, subscripts

if I try this;

```
Substituting the expression for \(\Psi\) in to the above and rearranging we derive an expression for the vacuum field \(\Psi'\) as a function of \(\mu \),

\begin{equation}
\Psi' = \frac{\Phi_t}{\mu ab\left[1+ \frac{4}{\pi^2}\sum_{m,n \mbox{ odd }} \frac{\alpha_{mn}}{mn}\right]} \\[1ex]
\end{equation}

with the sum being over odd \(m,n\). The total magnetic flux is defined as just the sum of the flu
```

Then it's weird because the {m,n \mbox{ odd }} is forced to the right of the summation instead of under it. This is because it's on the denominator. How do I fix this?

Comment: Perhaps this: `\begin{equation}
\Psi' = \frac{\Phi_t}{\mu ab\biggl[\displaystyle 1+ \frac{4}{\pi^2}\sum_{m,n \mbox{ odd }} \frac{\alpha_{mn}}{mn}\biggr]}
\end{equation}`.

Comment: ...or `\begin{equation}
\Psi' = \frac{\Phi_t}{\mu ab\left[1+ \dfrac{4}{\pi^2}\displaystyle\sum_{\smash{m,n \mbox{\scriptsize (odd) }}} \dfrac{\alpha_{mn}}{mn}\right]} \\[1ex]
\end{equation}` with the `amsmath` package loaded.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina -- rather than `\mbox` which would force the type to be the main body size, `\text` or `\textrm` would produce a more appropriate size.

Comment: @barbarabeeton yes, you're right; `\text` (if `amsmath` is loaded) or `\textrm` are better.

Comment: Or, if you don't want "odd" sticking off to the side, `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation} \Psi' = \frac{\Phi_t}{\mu ab\left[1+ \dfrac{4}{\pi^2}\displaystyle\sum_{\smash{\stackunder[1pt]{$\scriptstyle m,n$}{\tiny(odd)%
}}} \dfrac{\alpha_{mn}}{mn}\right]} \\[2ex] \end{equation} 
\end{document}`

Answer (score 1):

Summarizing the recommendations: (1) Use `\displaystyle` to increase generally the size of the `\sum` and fractions in the denominator, as well as change from subscript position to a limit under the sum. (2) Use `\textrm` or `\text` from the `amsmath` package instead of `\mbox`. `\mbox` uses the surrounding text font which is the wrong size for a subscript or limit and potentially the wrong font. (3) Also, it is useful to control the sizes of the brackets somehow and the vertical space taken up by the limit below the sum. This can be done by selecting an explicit size command for the brackets (`\biggl[` and `\biggr]`), and using `\smash` on the limit.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Substituting the expression for \(\Psi\) in to the above and rearranging
we derive an expression for the vacuum field \(\Psi'\) as a function of
\(\mu \),
\begin{equation}
  \Psi' = \frac{\Phi_t}{\mu ab \biggl[ \displaystyle 1 + \frac{4}{\pi^2}
          \sum_{\smash{m,n\ \textrm{odd}}} \frac{\alpha_{mn}}{mn}\biggr]}
\end{equation}
with the sum being over odd \(m,n\). The total magnetic flux is defined
as just the sum of the flu
\end{document}
```

If one only wants to change the position of the limits, one can just use `\sum\limits` in place of `\sum` (but also replace the `\mbox`).